# byte[]配列をBlob型に変換したい

Tags: java

Javaで byte[] 配列をBlobに変換するのってどうやるんでしたっけ？
Blobを `getByte()` で取得する方法は出てくるのですが、逆が出てきません。

Comment: 古いけどこの記事あたりでしょうか。[Byte array to blob in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25236792/9014308)

Answer (score 1):

[`Connection#createBlob()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#createBlob())を利用して生成したオブジェクトの[`setBytes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Blob.html#setBytes(long,byte%5B%5D))メソッドで実現できると思います。

- [JDBC 4.3 spec](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jdbc-4_3-mrel3-spec/jdbc4.3-fr-spec.pdf) 16.3.2 Creating Blob, Clob and NClob Objects

利用するJDBCドライバのリファレンスも参照してください。

Answer (score -1):

このあたりをご参考にすればいけえるかと、事例はbynaryStramですが、Byte配列からも
似たような方法でいけませんか？

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html